# Install url picture by Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am seeking for help I am trying to find solution to the macro below:
1st issue I want to paste url on column a and I would like the result picture on column b with the same size on the link column a

```
Sub InstallPictures()
    Dim i As Long, v As String
    On Error Resume Next
        For i = 2 To 1903
            v = Cells(i, "a").Value
            If v = "" Then Exit Sub
            With ActiveSheet.Pictures
                .Insert (v)
            End With
        Next i
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Sub InstallPictures()
Dim i As Long
Dim v As String
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim colWithUrl As Long, colWithPics As Long

colWithUrl = 1
colWithPics = 2

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("picture")
With sht
    .Columns(colWithPics).ColumnWidth = .Columns(colWithUrl).ColumnWidth
    For i = 2 To 3
        v = .Cells(i, colWithUrl).Value
        If v <> "" Then Call setPic(ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(v), .Cells(i, colWithPics), .Cells(i, colWithUrl))
    Next i
End With

End Sub


Sub setPic(myPic As Picture, cellToMoveImageTo As Range, cellToCopySizeFrom As Range)

With myPic.ShapeRange
    ' move image to have its upper left corner as the "cellToMoveImageTo" cell one
    .Left = cellToMoveImageTo.Left
    .Top = cellToMoveImageTo.Top


    ' resize the image to fit the "cellToCopySizeFrom" size
    .LockAspectRatio = False '<== you have to do that otherwise the original picture aspect ratio will stay and won't fit the aspect ratio of the cell whose upper left corner it shares
    .Height = cellToCopySizeFrom.Height
    .Width = cellToCopySizeFrom.Width

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You have to change "picture" with the actual name of the sheet you want to work with

Comment: if it works you may want to mark your question as answered, upvote my answer and/or give some rep. thank you

Comment: Still out of range did you test this from your side?

Comment: i got it now thanks but it is not working for the entire column,,for example if i put url in the entire column a then the result for all the link image will be in the column b

Comment: maybe you didn't notice that "For i = 2 to 3", by which I limited rows range for testing purposes. set that "3" to whatever you need.